# Simple nested class

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a beginner question regarding nested classes in c++. There are a lot of information on the internet about this but i still can't get it to work properly without compile errors. I simply want to return the inner class B from a function inside class A.

```
template<class T>
class A
{
      public:
      A();

      class B
      {
        public:
        B(){};
      };

      B getB();
};

template<class T>
A<T>::A(){}

template<class T>
B A<T>::getB{return B();}
```

When i do this i get the error "B does not name a type". I believe the solution is to use `typedef class A<T>::B b_class;`, but i still end up with the same error.

Thank you!

Comment: As a first step, try doing this outside of a template class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change a few things: add parens to the function definition, qualify the outer `B` with the enclosing class (`A<T>::`) alongside with `typename` (required because the type depends on the type of A) and change the return to actual object creation.

Here, listed in fixed source:

```
template<class T>
typename A<T>::B A<T>::getB() {return B();}
//^----------------------------------------------typename
//       ^---------------------------------------qualification
//                         ^---------------------parens
//                                     ^---------c-tor call
```

Comment: A description beyond that comment might be useful.  And why did you point out the parens at the end of `getB`?  What do you mean by `qualification`?

Comment: @Yakk because the original function was missing them?

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T>
B A<T>::getB{return B b;}
```

There are three issues here:

- `B` at the start of the declaration does not name the type `A<T>::B`. You need to be explicit about it, either by using `typename A<T>::B` or with a trailing return type so that `B` refers to the correct name.
- You don't have `()` after `getB`
- Your syntax for creating a temporary `B` is incorrect, it should be `B()` or `B{}`

Here is a fixed version:

```
template<class T>
auto A<T>::getB() -> B { return B{}; }
```

Comment: I like this version more than mine, actually. One thing that could be simplified is `return {};`, but that's a stylistic choice I guess.

Comment: Yeah, I find overzealous use of trailing return types a bit verbose, but it's quite nice in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`A` is the name of a template, so `A<T>` is the name of the (instantiated) class.

Thus, the full name of the nested class is `A<T>::B`, but since `B` depends on the template parameter `T` and is a type, you must specify `template A<T>::B`.

The tricky bits is that inside the declaration of `A` you can refer to `B` simply by using the `B` name. And you can refer to the instantiation of `A<T>` by using `A`, using what is called the *injected class name*. So inside the class declaration, `A` can refer both to the template and the class instantiation.

Answering your question:

```
template<class T>
typename A<T>::B A<T>::getB()
{
    B b;
    return b;
}
```

Note that the return type is outside the declaration of the function, so you need to use the fully qualified name.

Comment: Separating object creation from the return is completely unnecessary here.